# How to filter a collection in Laravel 5.5 based on multiple parameters?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, builder

I have a Profiles model, which have a few relationships (belongsTo, HasManyThought).

I want to filter based on several parameters, one after another.

For example:

- A select Input to select Categories (hasManyThough relationship).
- A select Input to select Locations.
- A text Input to type a few words and search through my model (and relationships).

**Profiles MODEL:**

```
    class Perfis extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];
    public function usuario(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }
    public function enderecos(){
        return $this->belongsTo (Enderecos::class);
    }

    public function categorias(){
        return $this->belongsToMany (

            Categorias::class,
            'perfis_categorias'
        );
    }

    // Filtros
    public function scopeFilter($query, $filtros){

        return $filtros->apply($query);

    }


}
```

**Profiles CONTROLLER**

public function index(PerfisFiltros $filtros, Request $request)
    {
        $perfis = Perfis::filter($filtros)->get();

```
    return view('frontal.perfis.index', [
        'perfis' => $perfis,
    ]);

}
```

**My Filters**

```
 public function apply($builder)
{
    if(! $this->request->has('_token')) return $builder;

    if($this->request->has('_token')){

            return $builder


            ->when($this->request->has('fCat'), function ($fCategoria) {
                $fCategoria->whereHas('categorias', function ($fCategoriaHas){
                    $fCategoriaHas->where('categorias_id', $this->request->fCat);
                });
            })
            ->when($this->request->has('fEstado'), function ($fEstado){
                $fEstado->whereHas('enderecos', function ($fEstadoHas){
                   $fEstadoHas->where('estados_id', $this->request->fEstado);
                });
            });
    }


}
```

Comment: So, what's the problem ?

Comment: The problem is that i'm only able to filter by one parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to wrap my head around what you are trying to do...but I straight away see that you are returning too early...here

```
if(! $this->request->has('_token')) return $builder;
```

And

```
if($this->request->has('_token')){

return $builder
```

You didnt give these guys a chance to run:

```
->when($this->request->has('fCat'), function ($fCategoria) {
                $fCategoria->whereHas('categorias', function ($fCategoriaHas){
                    $fCategoriaHas->where('categorias_id', $this->request->fCat);
                });
            })
            ->when($this->request->has('fEstado'), function ($fEstado){
                $fEstado->whereHas('enderecos', function ($fEstadoHas){
                   $fEstadoHas->where('estados_id', $this->request->fEstado);
                });
            });
```

Comment: That first "IF" statement is a negative. if the request Doesn't have a _token, it will return the $builder without parameters

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my needs, by changing my queries a little.

**My Filters**

```
if(!empty($this->request->fEstado)){
                $builder
                    ->whereHas('enderecos', function ($fEstadoHas){
                           $fEstadoHas->where('estados_id', $this->request->fEstado);
                        });
        }

        if(!empty($this->request->fCat)){
            $builder->whereHas('categorias', function ($fCat){
               $fCat->where('categorias_id', $this->request->fCat);
            });
        }


        if(!empty($this->request->fChave)){
            $builder->whereHas('anuncios', function ($fChave){
                $fChave->where('corpo', 'like', '%'.$this->request->fChave.'%')
                ->orWhere('titulo', 'like', '%'.$this->request->fChave.'%');
            });
        }



        return $builder;
```